# Is there a Free repository of pictures taken everyday of the night sky?

Tags: telescope, night-sky

I'd like to know if there's a repository out there of pictures taken everyday of the night sky. Not looking forward to anything fancy. Maybe a group of people out there have set up something out of their home telescopes or something.

Comment: http://www.allskycam.com/u.php?u=452 ? The term to look for is "all sky cameras". Someone from this set likely keeps a database online.

Comment: "Free" as in beer or "free" as in freedom? The pics @WayfaringStranger notes are beer-free, but are copyrighted, as the page notes.

Comment: I guess Free (with F, as in beer-wise) would be better (I'm a Free Software enthusiast myself so....)